# React, redux, dispatch action during render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm rendering different components on condition

```
  render() {

    switch(foo) {
    case 'a': return <A/>
    case 'b': return <B/>
    default: return <C/>
    }
  }
```

Now I want to track how many times each screen is visited, and do something like following

```
render() {

  switch(foo) {
  case 'a':
    this.props.dispatch(analytics.log({"screen": "A"}))
    return <A/>
  case 'b':
    this.props.dispatch(analytics.log({"screen": "B"}))
    return <B/>
  default:
    this.props.dispatch(analytics.log({"screen": "C"}))

    return <C/>

}
```

I'm getting an error `cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

I can't move the logging function call to `componentDidMount` because users move these screens like `tab` .

In this, case `render` is the perfect place to put the log, but react suggest me not to.

What can I do?

Comment: You should NOT be calling `dispatch` through `render()`. You can add event handlers, that call dispatches. Consider using `componentDidMount()`, and using a variable that dispatches a log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can't move this logic to `componentDidMount` because they all render at the same time (you mentioned Tabs), then i would move it to the `onClick` handler of the buttons that switch the tabs.

Comment: The render function returns a single component, so they aren't rendered at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Move the dispatch into the `componentDidMount` of your components `<A />`, `<B />` and `<C />`.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this into the onClick handler for each component.

e.g:

```
onClick = ('A'/'B'/'C') => {
    dispatch(analytics.log('A');
    history.push('A') or switch tab to ('A') // however you are handling tab change.
}
```

alternatively you could move the dispatch into the children components so when they are rendered, you dispatch the action there.

in  :

```
useEffect(() => { // or componentDidMount
 dispatch(analytics.log('A')
}, []) 

 // rest of A component.
```